# How to get Apple to repair iPhone under statutory warranty?

Tags: iphone, battery, repair, warranty

My iphone 5's battery after a bit more than a year is dying. I bought the iPhone via the German Apple Online Store. Hence I have 24 months of EU statutory warranty. The iPhone is otherwise in great condition and has no damages. 
When trying to use the online support and repair form, Apple wants to charge me 260€ for the repair. How can I tell Apple that i want it to be dealt with under the statutory warranty?
If Apple realizes that this isn't applicable, they should. Harge me at most the cost for replacing the battery, I think. And not the 260€ for a replacement device...

Comment: From whichever country you are now residing in, call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Danijel was right. The 0800 hotline did the trick. Apple was very willing to help and replaced the iPhone. Since it was only 13 months old and there were no damages, they handled it very quickly and without fuss.